# Getting the size of an entire iframe contents not including the scrollbars

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I am creating a web app where you can QA a website by writing notes and putting alerts on a canvas that will then be saved and sent off. What i need to know is how can i get the entire size of an iframe this means if you have to scroll down i need the size all the way to the bottom of the scroll bar although i do not wish to include the scroll bars.

This is so i can create a canvas that is the exact same size of the iframe and i can draw on top of it.

How would i go about getting this information?

Comment: is the content of the iframe on the same domain? there are security features that disable this for some browsers. can you use jQuery to get the content and append to a div instead of loading into an iframe?

Comment: No, the sites loaded into the iframe are external

Comment: If you can't control the iframe, you can't do anything due to the [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

using an iframe is not going to allow you to get to the content with javascript when the content is hosted from a different domina.

a possible solution would be something like

```
<html>
    <body>
        <object data="http://www.google.com" type="text/html"></object>
    <body>
</html>
```

not sure if this will work for you but could be a solution.

Comment: I already have an iframe loading external websites it does work.

Comment: @user3561158 Sorry, didnt mean to be unclear. Yes, you can load external sites, just can't get to them with js.

Comment: @user3561158, let me know if the edit makes my statement clearer. totally understand the miscommunication.